# WSO2 - Gracefully shut down docker container

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-esb

How do I gracefully shutdown docker container running WSO2 ESB? At the moment, I have to just kill the container running which might harm ongoing  transactions.

**Edit**

I am using the micro-integrator product.

Comment: Have you seen this github issue from last year: https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/issues/218 . It seems you are currently unable to do so. This might be in line with how docker works (i.e., checking for PID 1 to be alive, otherwise stop). Perhaps there is a way from the interface to shut the server down?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm referring to the ESB profile. However, will check your suggestion. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a container orchestration system such as Kubernetes, you can use prehooks for this. Please refer - https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-1/wso2am-pattern-1-am-deployment.yaml#L78

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm referring to the ESB profile. However, will check your suggestion. Thanks..

Comment: This is common to any application. You can use this for Esb as well.